# using the Frame() class to create frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frames

I am quite new to tkinter and I wonder how I should create frames.
If one is prefered over the other one, why is it so?

Is it better like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        main_frame = tk.Frame(parent)


root = tk.Tk()
main_app = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

or like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


root = tk.Tk()
main_app = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one creates *two* frames -- the instance itself (`main_app`) is a frame, and it contains a child frame (`main_frame`). Though, because you don't call the `__init__` of `Frame`, the first frame is not properly constructed.

If you are immediately going to create an internal frame and put everything inside it, it's pointless to inherit from `Frame`.

By the way, your code doesn't quite work. If you want to actually see the application widget (and its children) then you're going to need to call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on the widget.

For example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
main_app = MainApplication(root)
main_app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But doesn't the init func run when i create the instance? In this case "main_frame"

Comment: @Alex: the `__init__` that you define is run. The `__init__` of the class you inherit from is not run unless you explicitly call it (eg: `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)`)